# git migration error: [remote rejected] master -> master (cannot combine normal pushes and magic pushes)

Tags: gerrit

I would like to migrate a repo from server-A to server-B, here is my procedure:

1. "git clone --mirror" a repo, named test from server-A

> ```
> $ git clone --mirror ssh://my.name@10.58.65.50:29418/test
> Cloning into bare repository 'test.git'...
> remote: Counting objects: 1836, done
> remote: Finding sources: 100% (1829/1829)
> remote: Total 2758 (delta 377), reused 2664 (delta 377)
> Receiving objects: 100% (2758/2758), 1.28 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Resolving deltas: 100% (949/949), done.
> Checking connectivity... done.
> ```

2. Create an empty repo (test) on server-B
3. "git push --mirror" the repo (test) to server-B
   git push was failed, and the error log is listed as below:

> ```
> $ git push --mirror ssh://my.name@10.58.65.51:29418/test  
> Counting objects: 2661, done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (1713/1713), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (2661/2661), 1.25 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Total 2661 (delta 921), reused 2661 (delta 921)
> remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (921/921)
> remote: Processing changes: refs: 352, done    
> To ssh://my.name@10.58.65.51:29418/test
> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (cannot combine normal pushes and magic pushes)
> ! [remote rejected] refs/meta/config -> refs/meta/config (cannot combine normal pushes and magic pushes)
> ! [remote rejected] refs/changes/00/12100/1 -> refs/changes/00/12100/1 (cannot combine normal pushes and magic pushes)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://my.name@10.58.65.51:29418/test'
> ```

I have no idea of this error and how could I solve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1-Clone the empty repository from server B( make sure to clone it with commit msg)

2-Copy all your files from the 'A' server repository (except the .git file) to your empty 'B' server repository.

3-In your 'B' server repository run `git add .`
then `git commit -m 'your commit message'`

And then lastly `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master'`

Comment: I have a similar problem to that described by the OP.
I'm not altogether sure about this answer. Point 1: what you mean is "make sure to clone with commit msg _hooks_". 
Point 2: I see no .git file in the source repository, that only exists on my local clone. Furthermore, the hooks directory that was cloned from the empty repository will be overwritten anyway.
Question: are you describing a direct copy procedure from server A to server B, or are you copying via a local clone?